# Create new pages with a button using PageController

Tags: objective-c, uipagecontrol

How would I programmatically create new pages that are controlled by the PageControl dots? 
I want to create a button that makes pages. Each page should be added to the set of pages that you can flip through, using the page controller. 
How would I go about doing this? I know that you can create a page like this:

```
   -(IBAction)createPage:(id)selector {
    CustomPageClass *customPage=[CustomPageClass aloc];
    [self.view addSubView:customPage.view];
    }
```

However, when the button is clicked again, how do I make it so that the next "view" is on another page accesible by the PageController? 
Thanks much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right, you don't have to worry about create new page. It is done automatically. I hope it helps: 
http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/